# Require vs Import of Express Router to Prefix Routes

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I'm just starting out with Node using Express, and trying to use what I've learnt of Typescript in Angular by using TypeScript with Node.  Following [MDN's Express Route](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Introduction) example (about half way down) so I can prefix a set of routes with `/auth`.  They use `require('./routes/auth');` to get the exported router as I understood it using `import * as authRoutes from './routes/auth';` was equivalent based on docs and stackoverflow answers.  This apparently isn't true since I can't do this:

```
import * as authRoutes from './routes/auth';
app.use('/auth', authRoutes); // Does not work?
```

VSCode highlights the `'/auth'` param and show this error `[ts] Argument of type '"/auth"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams'`.

while this does work:

```
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
app.use('/auth', authRoutes); // Does work!
```

Routes from MDN Example:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import { Router, Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

import * as authController from '../controllers/auth.controller';

const router: Router = express.Router();

router.get('/register', (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  authController.register(req, res);
});

router.get('/login', (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  authController.login(req, res);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Can someone explain at a very high-level what I'm missing I'm finding what could be answers in blogs etc, but they are obviously not explained in a way that helps my understanding.

**UPDATE**

It seems like it is a combination of things since if I `export { router as authRoutes }` then it works, but I don't know if I should be doing that or not, or what the proper way to export and import our code into other files should follow.

Comment: Also, if there is a better way to prefix routes any links or suggestions are welcome

Comment: I'd also like to get an explanation. I am running into the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes definitions, export the router:

    `export { router };`

Import it in your app:

    `import { router as authRoutes } from 'routes';`